# SQL group by count across two tables

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I have got two tables called baseline and revisits

**baseline**

```
formid-------NoOfIssues

1--------------3

2--------------4

3--------------5
```

**revisits**

```
id------formid-------NoOfIssues-----------date--------------fid

1---------2--------------4-------------5/06/2016------------1

2---------3--------------3-------------15/06/2016-----------1

3---------1--------------4-------------20/07/2016-----------1

4---------1--------------3-------------25/07/2016-----------1

5---------2--------------5-------------28/07/2016-----------1

6---------1--------------5-------------01/06/2016-----------1

7---------3--------------8-------------21/02/2016-----------1

8---------3--------------2-------------21/02/2016-----------2
```

These tables are joined by 'formid'.
I need to compare number of issues in baseline vs revisits(only first) and get a count as **reduced**, **increased** or **equal**

Based upon the above table i am expecting the following, for example across all three baseline entries no equals were found comparing NoOfissues in first revisit against same formid, but 1 equal and 2 increased were found

Addition: if same date and same formid is found than take the lower fid, so in the last two rows of revisits table both formid and date are equal but need to consider the lower formid which is 1

```
status----------Count

reduced----------0

equal------------1

increased--------2
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: intersystem cache so simple sql

Comment: What do you want to do with cases where there are not revisits? First revisit determined by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with intersystems-cache, but you can see if the following is valid SQL with that DB:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN BL.NoOfIssues = FR.NoOfIssues THEN 'equal'
        WHEN BL.NoOfIssues > FR.NoOfIssues THEN 'reduced'
        WHEN BL.NoOfIssues < FR.NoOfIssues THEN 'increased'
    END AS status,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    Baseline BL
INNER JOIN Revisits FR ON FR.formid = BL.formid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Revisits R ON
    R.formid = BL.formid AND
    (
        R.date < FR.date OR
        (R.date = FR.date AND R.fid > FR.fid)
    )
WHERE
    R.formid IS NULL
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN BL.NoOfIssues = FR.NoOfIssues THEN 'equal'
        WHEN BL.NoOfIssues > FR.NoOfIssues THEN 'reduced'
        WHEN BL.NoOfIssues < FR.NoOfIssues THEN 'increased'
    END
```

Some quick notes on your database though - You should probably decide on a standard of plural or singular table names and stick with it. Also, try to avoid common reserved words for object names, like date. Finally, if a revisit is basically the same as a visit, just on a later date then you should consider keeping them all in the same table.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the answer, its spot on as you considered lower date as well, but please see if its possible to consider where both formid and date are same then it should only consider the NoOfIssues from lower fid, like the last two columns its should take NoOfIssues as 8 and ignore the row with higher fid where NoOfIssues is 2

Comment: It should just be an additional criteria in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. I've added the code that I think should do it.

Comment: i tried to give you another point it took away one. so i put it back

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in one row rather than three:

```
select sum(case when numissues = rcnt then 1 else 0 end) as equal,
       sum(case when numissues > rcnt then 1 else 0 end) as reduced,
       sum(case when numissues < rcnt then 1 else 0 end) as incrased
from (select b.form_id, b.numissues, count(r.form_id) as rcnt
      from baseline b left join
           revisits r
           on b.form_id = r.form_id
      group by b.form_id, b.numissues
     ) br;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a window function to get the number of ussues at the minimum date, then compare that to the baseline number of issues

```
select
    case when baseline.NoOfIssues = rev.NoOfIssues then 'equal'
         when baseline.NoOfIssues > rev.NoOfIssues then 'reduced'
         when baseline.NoOfIssues < rev.NoOfIssues then 'increased'
    end as status,
    count(*) as count
from baseline
inner join(
    select
        formid,
        case when date = min(date) over(partition by formid) then NoOfIssues else null end as first_rev_issues
    from revisits
) rev
on baseline.formid = rev.formid
group by
    case when baseline.NoOfIssues = rev.NoOfIssues then 'equal'
         when baseline.NoOfIssues > rev.NoOfIssues then 'reduced'
         when baseline.NoOfIssues < rev.NoOfIssues then 'increased'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT
BL.FORMID, 
BL.NOOFISSUES AS BLI, 
RV.NOOFISSUES AS RVI, 
RV.DATE,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BL.FORMID ORDER BY RV.DATE) AS RN
FROM Baseline BL
INNER JOIN Revisits RV ON RV.FORMID = BL.FORMID
)

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN RVI > BLI THEN 1 END), 0) AS INCREASED,
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN RVI < BLI THEN 1 END), 0) AS DECREASED, 
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN RVI = BLI THEN 1 END), 0) AS EQUAL
FROM CTE
WHERE RN=1;
```

Comment: Hi Newbie92, Thanks for your solution. It seems the CTE is not supported by Intersystem SQL. I have also updated my problem with another check that needs to be performed when both date and formid are the same then lower fid needs to be considered.